# I have deployed my Telegram Bot on Heroku but it is not running on Telegram

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, telegram-webhook

I was able to run my telegram bot with Python locally on my machine without problems and have deployed it on heroku with it stating that Build succeeded. However, when I try to use my bot on telegram, it does not respond. What may be the problem? Here is the code to my main file:

https://github.com/PlatinumCreatine/UNABLE-TO-RUN.git

Comment: Add token. Probably you forgot that.

Comment: Make sure the webhook URL has a forward slash `/` before the token (ie https://myapp.herokuapp.com/<token>)